# How to filter ng-repeat on a child value using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I've made a simple table with repeating rows based on an array using ng-repeat.
I've added a filter similar [to this example](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter).

My problem comes when I try to filter on the nested object.  It is always a single object, basically it is the parent to my current object but it's the full object instead of just the FK value.

If I use filterText.educationCenter.name it filters all rows out of the table and will not return them even if I clear the filter.  I have to do a full reload.

If I filter on just filterText.educationCenter it will work but it searches all fields of the entire object.

I would like to keep the JSON as it is and filter the table results based on the name of the educationCenter object.

My HTML

```
Search: <input ng-model="filterText.$"/>
<input ng-model="filterText.city"/>
<input ng-model="filterText.educationCenter.name"/>

<tr ng-repeat="course in courses | filter:filterText | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
                    <td width="145">{{course.city}}</td>
                    <td width="145">{{course.educationCenter.name}}</td>
...
```

My JSON for a singe object from the array

```
{"id":"108"
,"city":"My City"
,"educationCenter":{"id":"3"
                   ,"description":"This is the ed center description"
                   ,"name":"test ed center 1"}
,"noOfDays":"1"}
```

Comment: You can always write your custom filter functions

Answer (score 0):

As @fastreload suggested, I think you'll have to make your own filter.

Here is the sample of the recursive filter.
(it does not support `$` notation though, and I'm sure it is missing
 some edge case support.)

```
app.filter('recursiveFilter', function() {
  var compare = function(input_, cond_) {
    if (!cond_) return true;
    if (typeof input_ == "string" && typeof cond_ == "string") {
      return (new RegExp(cond_)).test(input_);
    } else if (typeof input_ == "object" && typeof cond_ == "object") {
      for (var s in cond_) {
        if (!compare(input_[s], cond_[s])) return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };

  return function(inputs, cond) {
    return $.grep(inputs, function(input) {
      return compare(input, cond);
    });
  };
});
```